# How to constantly change the background image/color depending on the current time's day?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to improve my website for a project in my college.
What exactly I'm trying to do is to change the background according to the time.
Imagine this scenario, changing the background color to a linear-gradient background image, according to a specific day time.

Example:
   From 7am to 1pm, have this background: 
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, yellow 0%, red 100%)
   From 1pm to to 6pm, have this background:
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #003366 0%, #000d1a 100%);
   And, for the rest, have this background:
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #000d1a 0%, #000000 100%);

All I have so far, that could help me figure out a way to do it on HTML using JavaScript, is this:

```
On HTML:

<script type=”text/javascript” src=”script.js”> </script>


var date=new Date();

var hour=data.getHours();

if (hour<13)
{
    alert("Good Morning!");
}
else if (hour<18)
{
    alert("Good Evening!");
}
else 
{
    alert("Good Night!");
}
```

(Used the commands "alert" as an example of what I could fit in it to change the background, which is the command I'm currently looking for)

I'd like to apologize for any wrong grammar or directory, or anything else I did wrong. Feel free to correct me on everything.

If someone could give me an example of a simple HTML syntax on html with the javascript code inside of it, not in another directory, that'd truly help! Either way, thank you for taking your time to help me out! =D

If everything goes as expected, I'll be posting my website here to share with everyone, I think it would be a good thing for people to see each others projects. In the project I'm currently working for, I'm responsible for the website development, which is going to be showing to the user the pros and cons of using a photovoltaic plate in a domestic/company area, also using a Solar Tracking device on it. In the website, we're going to have the results to everything related to it, I'll make sure to translate it from portuguese to english too.
Have a good day.

Comment: So you don't know how to use JS to change element background-color?

Comment: replace `alert` with `document.body.style.background = '<your favorite color here>';`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a timeout to check the current time.

```
function VerifyTime(){

    var hour=new Date().getHours();

    if (hour<13)
    {
        alert("Good Morning!");
    }
    else if (hour<18)
    {
        alert("Good Evening!");
    }
    else 
    {
        alert("Good Night!");
    }
}

window.setTiemout(function(){VerifyTime()},<time>})
```

the time is expressed in milliseconds: 1 sec = 1000, i suggest you checking at each minute with 60000 or at every second with 1000

Answer (score 0):

Just use CSS classes to display the background you want :

```
<style>
.morning{
  background: morningColor;
}
.evening{
  background: eveningColor;
}
.night{
  background: nightColor;
}
</style>
```

Then replace your alert by adding the corresponding class:

```
<script> 
  var hour=new Date().getHours(); // get current hour value
  var elem = document.body.getElementById(<your element id>); // you can trigger a specific element via id for example
  if (hour<13){
    elem.className += 'morning';
  }
  else if (hour<18){
    elem.className += 'evening';
  }
  else{
    elem.className += 'night';
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to do:

```js
var date = new Date();

var hour = date.getHours();

if (hour < 13) {
  alert("Good Morning!");
  document.body.classList.add('morning'); // Based on the current time, add a class to the document's body
} else if (hour < 18) {
  alert("Good Evening!");
  document.body.classList.add('evening');
} else {
  alert("Good Night!");
  document.body.classList.add('night');
}
```

```css
.morning {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.evening {
  background-color: orange;
}

.night {
  background-color: black;
}

/** These colours are just examples, style them in the way you need them to be */
```